# Level tracking using optical or capacitance sensors

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am looking to devise a level tracking system using arduino and some sensors. My particular situation is I have solute that is coming out of solution and I want to track the formation rate of the solid phase as the salts settle at the bottom and build a bed of particulates.

I am looking for precision at about 0.5mm and over a range of like 6 inches. My initial idea was to get a sensor bar that could detect when and where light is hitting the sensor and post processes that signal. I have to design this device to sit outside the cylindrical vessel. The solvent is transparent so any form of light would work. I am stuck on finding the parts that could pull this off and I was hoping the more experienced community could point in the right direction.

*** UPDATE ***

a little cartoon for a clearer picture of the idea 
I am leaning towards capacitance since using light seems like a rabbit hole. I was playing with some foil and it may work but I need a much more sensitive tool on the order of pico-Farads to work.

[image]

Comment: What is the distance between the sensors? If it's a short distance, you could possibly get away with using two clear tubes and putting sensors in one tube and then lights in another tube.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin The diameter of the tube that contains the liquid I want to measures is on the order of 3cm. My best thought thus far was to go for an approach parallel plate capacitors, but I am not sure that would work to well.  I need really high resolution since the materials would have low k values.

Comment: Ultrasonic sensor?

Comment: @RSM how would that work? I am thinking I need to account for possibly 6 inches in elevation change.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice the time from the transmit to the time of receive would change as the level increases. If the liquid level increase with proportionally to the increase of the solid the level sensor could work. Also there capacitive sensors for level sensing, partially described here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_sensor

Comment: @RSM Thanks for the link! The problem is for my experiment I cannot have anything inside the tube I must measure the level externally. Also I am looking to get the level as a function of time so I need a continuous means of measurement.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice so in terms of in the tube and the ultrasonic sensor, if that works, can sit above the vessel.

Comment: @RSM top or bottom is not workable because of flow inlets and outlets. I am trying to get the height without intruding. This is tube is hooked up to a machine. I can only attack it from the sides. Thanks for all the great suggestions though!

Comment: @TheCodeNovice - possibly if you isolate the capacitive sensor on the outside of the tube from the interference of air, it should increase the accuracy to a point.

Comment: What solution is it?

Comment: @RSM how could i isolate from air interference?

Comment: @TheCodeNovice - I don't know off hand what would be best but I am sure a Google search should give something. It should basically keep the surrounding air at a constant so that it doesn't change with changing air flow(blocking movement from changing the level) if possible you could put a plastic tube around the other tube and seal the ends. That's if you can get something around withe the other stuff.

Comment: A quick search for “capacitive water sensor” gives [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Building-a-Capacitive-Liquid-Sensor/?ALLSTEPS).

Comment: Light might be the way to go, since the preciptate might not have significantly different capacitive or acoustic properties   How about a laser-sensor pair shining through to a sensor on a movable servo or stepper-driven stage, and you move the stage upwards/tube downwards whenever the laser diffuses into the precipitate, keeping track of the motion of the stage?

Answer (score 1):

What about measuring this with two resistive probes - the electricity will go through down one probe to the top of the water, across the water, and up the other probe. You can measure how much of the probe it went down, by measuring the resistance. You would need the probes to be a specific, very consistent distance apart, and be made of resistance wire.

Another option is to use a float of some kind, and measure it this way. This is a lot easier if all you need to know is full/not full.